# manipulate URL in django - middleware

Tags: python, django

I have

```
id=request.GET.get('id',None)
```

in a middleware file

which receives website.com/?id=12 in the URL 
and I can save it in a session ,

```
request.session['id'] =id
```

but
now I want to receive a url like this :  website.com/@id

How can I retrieve the data like that? I am not asking for url.py Path

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use [**`request.path` or `request.path_info`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path). Like this:

```
def simple_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        _id = request.path
        request.session['id'] =_id 
        response = get_response(request)

        return response

    return middleware
```